# Keyboard shortcut to add new Gmail contact?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have looked through the keyboard shortcuts and searched as best I can and I cannot seem to find a keyboard shortcut to add a new contact. It must be staring me right in the face, but I'm not seeing it.

To be clear on what I'm talking about: I'm referring to the scenario where I am in the main screen of the Gmail contact manager, looking at my list of contacts. There is a big red button labeled "New Contact" that I can click on to add a new contact. That's great. I just want to do that exact same action with a keyboard shortcut. The same as what I can do with 'c' and 'shift-c' in Gmail to compose a new message.

So far the best I have been able to do is <kbd>/</kbd> (to get to the search box), then <kbd>tab</kbd> nine times, then <kbd>space</kbd>. But that is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way of doing this. Hitting `/` and tabbing over is the easiest way without generating a custom keyboard shortcut outside of the Gmail Contacts framework.

Comment: OK, thanks. I suppose I'll just create an AutoHotkey shortcut to send the necessary keystrokes.